# Python boto3 script for fetching info of Users who doesn't activated their MFA device

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am new to python and boto3. Pardon me if this is not the right place to ask.

Can anyone help me to write a script to fetch all the **Users who doesn't activated their MFA device**. I can get the same from credentials reports. But i want to fetch the info using script.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('iam')
iam_users = []
response = client.list_users()
for user in response['Users']:
    iam_users.append(user['UserName'])
while 'Marker' in response:
    response = client.list_users(Marker=response['Marker'])
    for user in response['Users']:
        iam_users.append(user['UserName'])

no_mfa_users = []
for iam_user in iam_users:
    response = client.list_mfa_devices(UserName=iam_user)
    if not response['MFADevices']:
        no_mfa_users.append(iam_user)
```

`no_mfa_users` array will contain a list of IAM Users without MFA enabled.

boto3 reference can be found [here](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.list_mfa_devices).

Answer (score 0):

This is the lambda function which helps you to define the users that doesn't activated the MFA on their account. Also i am adding SNS topic to the function which will send you the list to the defined topic.

```
import boto3

client=boto3.client('iam')
sns=boto3.client('sns')

response = client.list_users()
userVirtualMfa = client.list_virtual_mfa_devices()
physicalString = ''


def lambda_handler(event,context):
 mfa_users=[]
 for user in response['Users']:

    userMfa = client.list_mfa_devices(UserName=user['UserName'])

    for uname in userMfa['MFADevices']:
        virtualEnabled = []
        virtualEnabled.append(uname['UserName'])

    if len(userMfa['MFADevices']) == 0 :

        if user['UserName'] not in virtualEnabled:
            mfa_users.append(user['UserName'])

 print (mfa_users)
```